# Why does Visual Studio call the destructor here but GCC does not?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, gcc

Win32 Console Project in Visual C++ 2010 Express running on Win7, 64-bit.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>

class Num
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    friend Num operator+(Num, Num);

    // Constructor
    Num(int i)
    {
        printf("buidling %p\n", this);
        this->value = i;
    }
    // Deconstructor
    ~Num()
    {
        printf("destroying %p\n", this);
    }
    // Getter for value
    int getVal()
    {
        return value;
    }
};

// Overload "+" operator
Num operator+(Num i, Num j)
{
    printf("in operator+\n");
    return (i.value + j.value);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Num a = Num(42) + 17;
    printf("done %p %d\n", &a, a.getVal());

    // Hold up
    printf("Press any key to continue...\n");
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

When I watch the construction process in VC++, the object for Num(17) gets created, then the object for Num(42), then the Num a.  All good so far.  On destruction, there is a 4th object destructed prior to destruction of the temporary 17 and 42 objects, and finally a.  The `printf` reveals this has something to do with the overloaded operator+.  It would appear that VC++ creates 1 additional temporary Num object without using the constructor that it then copies to a and calls the destructor on.  By contrast, it seems that GCC creates this copy and then assigns a to that memory rather than creating this copy.

Two questions:

1. Am I correctly interpreting what VC++ is doing here?  Why is the destructor used, but not the constructor?
2. Why are they handled differently?  It would seem that GCC's approach would be more efficient as it creates/destroys 1 fewer object.  Any benefits to the VC++ approach?

Comment: Trace all constructors and assignment operators and the destructor (C++11 has 5)

Comment: Do you get the same output with full optimizations on (VC++ release build and GCC -O3)?

Answer (score 2):

You are not outputing anything in `Num`'s **copy constructor**, you need to add that:

```
Num(const Num &i)
{
    printf("buidling %p\n", this);
    this->value = i.value;
}
```

Your `operator+()` implementation is taking its input `Num` objects **by value** so copies are being made. Change `operator+()` to take the objects **by `const` reference** instead to avoid that:

```
Num operator+(const Num &i, const Num &j)
```

Lastly, consider implementing `operator+()` as a member of `Num` instead of a standalone function:

```
class Num
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    //...

    // Getter for value
    int getVal() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    // Overload "+" operator
    Num operator+(const Num &j) const
    {
        printf("in operator+\n");
        return (value + j.getVal());
    }
};
```

Or:

```
class Num
{
private:
    int value;
public:
    //...

    // Getter for value
    int getVal() const
    {
        return value;
    }

    // Overload "+=" operator
    Num& operator+=(const Num &j)
    {
        printf("in operator+=\n");
        value += j.getVal();
        return *this;
    }

    // Overload "+" operator
    Num operator+(const Num &j) const
    {
        printf("in operator+\n");
        Num tmp(*this);
        tmp += j;
        return tmp;
    }
};
```

Comment: Standalone operators are better if you want to have implicit type conversion on both sides of it. On the other hand, implicit type conversions can be very, very surprising...

Comment: Passing the input `Num` objects by `const` reference also allows for implicit conversions.  Passing them by value does not. And you probably don't want an implicit conversion on the left-side of `+`, though, otherwise the compiler might call the wrong `+` operator to begin with.